# Gradle Build Failed React native: > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

Hey Guys I have the folowing error when trying to build my app with gradle `compileSdkVersion is not specified` though I already declared the compileSdkVersion in the build.gradle file

Here's the error
[image]

And Here my `build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        kotlinVersion = "1.5.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```